How to fix frames flicker on headless rendering on RTX A4000?
Headless rendering with a python script
I am rendering many frames or instances heedlessly with a single script. I use Mesh-to-Points geometry node with a vertex only mesh. I get patches of my frames missing.
This is shown in the pictures. The same object is rendered at 0 deg Z then at 30 deg Z and chunks of vertices are missing. I also attach the composite nodes in case it is affecting it.
I am using the cycles editor but this was also an issue with EEVEE.
Blender 4.2.3 LTS on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS. Headless (blender -b <file.blend> --python render.py). Using 2 RTX A4000
This is also an issue if I render an animation using bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True). Some frames flicker with patches missing



import bpy
from math import pi

def load_pointcloud(target_obj: str, pointcloud_path: str):
    #    bpy.ops.wm.ply_import(filepath=pointcloud_path)
    bpy.ops.import_mesh.ply(filepath=pointcloud_path, use_verts=True)
    new_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

    og_obj = bpy.data.objects.get(target_obj)

    cp_verts(target_obj=og_obj, src_obj=new_obj)

    new_obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
    bpy.data.objects.remove(new_obj, do_unlink=True)

def render_at_angle(target_object: str, angle: float, output_path: str):
    og_obj = bpy.data.objects.get(target_object)
    og_obj.rotation_euler[2] = angle * pi / 180

    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.compute_device_type = "CUDA"
    bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.get_devices()
    bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.devices[0].use = True
    bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = "GPU"

    angles = (0.0, 30.0, 60.0)
    for id_ in id_list:
        load_pointcloud("rec_pointmap", f"input_folder/{id_}_pcan.ply")
        for angle in angles:
            render_at_angle("rec_pointmap", angle, rf"path/{id_}_{int(angle)}.png")



Rendering from command line is quite robust, so it must be the script. What script? If you are just simply using a loop to render, that's the problem. The script does not just simply wait for render to finish. See this for an example how to render multiple times using a modal operator. No idea if it works from command line though. I have only used that to render from the UI.

I might be mistaken about this. I always need UI preview, so maybe it only doesn't work with "INVOKE_DEFAULT".

I added an abridged version of my script. It works 99% of the time, and does appear from the script outputs and success rate to be blocking but I can try something like this. Thanks! (edit I am doing about 500 frames at a time)
